cargo lambda build--arm64 not working on al2023
I'm trying to build Rust for Lambda runtime with Amazon Linux 2023(al2023), so  everything is running on Docker as below
# Use cargo-lambda as the build environment
FROM ghcr.io/cargo-lambda/cargo-lambda:latest as builder

# Create app directory
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the Cargo.toml and Cargo.lock files
COPY . .

# Build the release version of your application
RUN cargo lambda build --arm64 --release

# Use the AWS Lambda provided base image for custom runtimes
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/provided:al2023

# Copy the compiled binary from the builder stage
COPY --from=builder /app/target/lambda/user/bootstrap ${LAMBDA_RUNTIME_DIR}

# Set the CMD to your handler
CMD ["bootstrap"]

The docker file works fine and I can run it with docker run --rm -it -p 9000:8080 my-rust-lambda
but when I call the endpoint, I got qemu-aarch64: Could not open '/lib/ld-linux-aarch64.so.1': No such file or directory
what do I miss?

Does the base Docker image support aarch64, or the container is running on an aarch64 based machine?

@Dodge_X the docker image supports aarch64 as I understand from https://gallery.ecr.aws/lambda/provided

or maybe the base image needs some extra library? might this can help https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/751329/qemu-aarch64-could-not-open-lib-ld-linux-aarch64-so-1-no-such-file-or-direc

@Dodge_X not tried that yet but it works now if I add FROM --platform=linux/arm64 public.ecr.aws/lambda/provided:al2023. it will show warning like WARNING: The requested image's platform (linux/arm64/v8) does not match the detected host platform (linux/amd64) and no specific platform was requested but it's working

understood.  the problem is that you built the image in an amd64 based machine, but you want to run it on an arm64 based machine. You do need to add the 'platform' option.

new Dockerfile
# Use cargo-lambda as the build environment
FROM ghcr.io/cargo-lambda/cargo-lambda:latest as builder

# Create app directory
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the Cargo.toml and Cargo.lock files
COPY . .

# Build the release version of your application
RUN cargo lambda build --arm64 --release

# Use the AWS Lambda provided base image for custom runtimes
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/provided:al2023

# Copy the compiled binary from the builder stage
COPY --from=builder /app/target/lambda/user/bootstrap ${LAMBDA_RUNTIME_DIR}

# Set the CMD to your handler
CMD ["bootstrap"]

